# Transfer-Encoding Chunked Box-API

Tags: box-api, chunked, transfer-encoding

I would like to know if ***-H "transfer-encoding: chunked"*** is supported in Box.net?

```
curl --verbose https://www.box.com/api/2.0/files/content -H "Authorization: BoxAuth api_key=zzgfxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxqnvucpz&auth_token=09ngxxxxxxxxxx3esvtx2" -H "transfer-encoding: chunked" -F filename=@Bike.pdf -F folder_id=436000003
```

Answer (score 0):

Box does not currently support chunked uploads, although we do plan to do so in the future.  No definite timeline for adding it at the moment.